# SQL for each type return difference based on another column min/max

Tags: sql

I am practicing SQL and run into a task I have no idea how to deal with.
I am supposed to write a query that will select event_type registered more than once and difference between values (most recent and second most recent observation in terms of another column time).
Example table looks like this

```
   event_type | value      | time1
  ------------+------------+--------------------
   2          | 5          | 2015-05-09 12:42:00
   4          | -42        | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   2          | 2          | 2015-05-09 14:48:30
   2          | 7          | 2015-05-09 12:54:39
   3          | 16         | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   3          | 20         | 2015-05-09 15:01:09
```

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    event_type int,
    value int,
    time1 datetime
);
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2, 5, '2015-05-09 12:42:00');
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (4, -42, '2015-05-09 13:19:57')
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2, 2, '2015-05-09 14:48:30');
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2,7, '2015-05-09 12:54:39');
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (3,16, '2015-05-09 13:19:57');
INSERT INTO events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (3,20, '2015-05-09 15:01:09');
```

and return should look like this:

```
 event_type | value
  ------------+-----------
   2          | -5
   3          | 4
```

For event_type 2 most recent value is 2 and second most recent is 7 so 2-7 = -5.

Comment: Are you using any particular SQL *flavor* (MySQL, SQL Server, DB2, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This one is fun!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#events') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #events
CREATE TABLE #events (
    event_type int,
    value int,
    time1 datetime
);
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2, 5, '2015-05-09 12:42:00');
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (4, -42, '2015-05-09 13:19:57')
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2, 2, '2015-05-09 14:48:30');
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (2,7, '2015-05-09 12:54:39');
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (3,16, '2015-05-09 13:19:57');
INSERT INTO #events (event_type, value, time1)
VALUES (3,20, '2015-05-09 15:01:09');


SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [rank] = 2 THEN -[value] ELSE [value] END) [output]
    ,event_type
FROM(
    SELECT
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY time1 DESC) [Rank]
    ,*
    FROM #events
)A
WHERE [Rank] <= 2
GROUP BY event_type
HAVING COUNT(event_type) > 1
```

Output: [image]

-Use a window function to rank records grouped by event_type and ordered by time Descending.

-Use outer query to filter out records that are beyond 2nd most recent time (rank > 2)

-Make records that are second most recent negative, and aggregate the values grouped by event_type

-Having Clause can filter out event_type values that do not have a 2nd most recent record, like event_type = 4. (Count of event_type is > 1)